# Ghost raycaster still sending events after removal?

Tags: aframe

In the following scene, I'm trying to understand why after clicking the sphere to switch cameras and cursors (via.removeAttribute/.setAttribute) still seems to swap back [even if I click outside the sphere](https://gyazo.com/767999ced507cfa19f4a09e93bb41c02)--even though the scene inspector shows no cursor or raycaster on firstCursorEl to cause the ghost click event. The test scene's at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWJrXe, let me know if I'm missing something important! (jhsu mentioned needing to bind render-target-loaded to wait for a loaded canvas element if .removeAttribute('cursor') was called on-init, but I'm assuming that doesn't need to happen on-click.) Here's what the entity HTML given by the inspector looks like after a swap, if it helps:

```
<a-entity print-onenter="" id="firstCursorEl" mixin="avatarCursor"></a-entity>
<a-entity print-onenter="" mixin="avatarCursor" id="secondCursorEl" raycaster="" cursor=""></a-entity>
```

Where firstCursorEl is a child of the starter camera, and secondCursorEl a child of the camera we swap to. Since secondCursorEl's cursor/raycaster are aimed away from the swap-button-sphere (unless they're somehow out of sync with the camera gaze's direction?), and firstCursorEl seems to have no such components, how does it still swap back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by Don McCurdy: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/2397 to implement cursor remove handlers.

You can use this build: `<script src="https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/84c6431/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>` to pull it in until 0.5.1 or 0.6.0 is out.